# Get fields of generic type object in Java

Tags: java, generics, resttemplate

I have a class called "Person":

```
public Class Person {
    String name;
    String address;
}
```

A public method is used to return a Person object by using RestTemplate as below.  My question is that how I print the name and the address of the Person object if I use generic type T for Person?  I know I can do "instanceOf", but if "log" needs to handle many different types, then I will have to do "instanceOf" for each of them.  Anyone has a better approach? Thanks.

```
public Person getPerson(SomeObject request) throws Exception {

    String url =......;
    return post(url, request, Pereson.class);
}

// This method can be used by response types other than Person
private <T> T post(String url, 
                   Object request, 
                   Class<T> responseType) throws Exception {

    T response = 
          restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, responseType);

    log(response, responseType);
    return response;
  }

private <T> void log(T response, 
                     Class<T> responseType) throws Exception {

    // how do I print the name and the address of the 
    // Person response object here?
 }
```

Comment: Override `toString` method in `Person` and call it in `log`.

Comment: Cast the return for ```postForObject``` to T

Comment: @j.seashell  I don't think I understand.  postForObject returned a T, were you saying something different?

Comment: Well, you have to give some restriction. You question is akin to "how do I write a method that does something different for each type of input?" and you say that there are too many inputs so you don't want to check for each of them. You have to unify the inputs in some way so that they can all be handled similarly, and that depends also on what the logging method needs to do exactly for each input.

Comment: for (Field f:responseType.getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(f.get(response));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do in this context is to delegate to the instance.  Since you have no way to determine *what* that instance will be - it may be anything, really - the most effective way to log out critical information about the response would be to just invoke `toString` on `response`.

This means you need a suitable `toString` method attached to `Person`, which displays the name and address.

Anything *else* - dealing with `instanceof` or any kind of dodgy casting - is too risky and brittle when you need to introduce new classes which have to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasonable approached.

- Have `Person` implement a `Printable` interface and declare `T extends Person`. (Using `Object::toString` makes this simpler, but may be the wrong thing to do.)
- Add an adaptor (probably functional) interface, `Printer` (or even `Printer<T>`), to stand in for `Person`. Write a set of overloaded static (or not) functions to wrap the likes of `Person` into `Printer`s (or even write inline as a lambda).